# How to generate Email alert by comparing dates?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

I have made a web application which runs on apache tomcat and is coded in JSP. It uses jdbc to connect to a mysql database to enter/manipulate values from the web interface

I now want to compare current date  with a column called expiry date in mysql database. If on comparing the current date and all the expiry dates in the database a difference of 30 days is found in any expiry date, it should generate an email alert .(send an email about expiry to a pre defined email address)

I have stored the date in mysql as varchar() type as i was having some problems using date type.

How can i achieve this? I want that everyday this code should run once for checking if any dates in the database are expiring

Comment: And... what have you tried?

Comment: i tried using Java.Util to get current date, I can fetch the expiry date column from the databse, However i cannot figure out how to compare the results from sql query and immediately generate a mail if the condition of 30 days is met.

Comment: And what is the format that the expiry date is stored in the db?

Comment: as i mentioned above it is stored in varchar (however when a user enters the date from the web interface it is in yyyy/mm/dd format as i use a calender of java script for the input of date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for cron job, you can see a example here http://makdns.blogspot.com/2011/02/java-servlet-cron-job-thoruhg-tomcat.html

You first create a job which is actually a java class file that do your business, it should for instance get all the record from the DB, compare the date and send the email; next you have to setup your cronjob option to re-run that job daily or weekly... it depend in your app size.

You should google with the cron jobs, cron tasks key word for more information.

**Edit**
You can parse and create the date object something like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // or whatever format you have
Date dateFromDB = sdf.parse("String from your date column in database");
Date now = new Date();

if(now.getTime() - dateFromDB.getTime() > 30 x 24 x 3600 x 1000) {
    // TODO alert email
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: yes, this is the second part of my problem, cron job would help me generate the emails. But firstly , how can i compare the results from the expiry column of my database with current date? since the current date needs to be compared with all the entires in the expiry column

Comment: You should read or search for its java docs for more information.

Comment: thank you, i think this should solve my problem!